# Timer Input Capture using DMA

Tags: timer, stm32, capture, dma

How can I detect the rising edge of a 10 MHz signal using STM32F429 input capture DMA? I want to scan all GPIOD pins at every rising edge of the mentioned signal.
Note: ABP2 timer clock frequency is 160 MHz